# Adding updates to current QGIS version from later ones?

Tags: qgis, installation, update

I am currently using version 3.4 of QGIS, and I was wondering if it is possible to implement all of the awesome changes from version 3.5, 3.6, etc. into version 3.4 or do I need to keep installing the new versions if I want access to the new features?

Comment: If you want new features, you need to upgrade to new versions. Generally only bug/security fixes get backported to long-term release versions.  There isn't a 3.5 release, QGIS only releases even number (3.2, 3.4, 3.6 etc.) point releases, the odd number is only used for development snapshots/branches.

Comment: You can install more than one version of QGIS on the same computer. I do this for projects that have been done by other people. Running 3.4 & 3.6 currently.